# Objective-C errors with Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I added a simple class to my Xcode command line tool project. The class is shown below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Foo : NSObject {
}
@end
```

and

```
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo
@end
```

As soon as I reference *Foo.h* using `#import "Foo.h"` in my main file I get all type of errors. I have Foundation.frameowork added as my frameworks.

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/
    Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/
NSObjCRuntime.h:189:1: error: expected identifier or '(' [3]

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/
    Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/
NSObjCRuntime.h:197:50: error: unknown type name 'Protocol' [3]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing that you probably need to rename `main.c` to `main.m`? Otherwise, can you post the content of your main file?

Comment: Awesome! It worked! Thanks man! So, what is the reason behind this that .c did not work but .m worked!

Comment: The reason is simple: C and Objective-C are not the same language. Compiling your code as C means that Objective-C features such as classes will not be understood by the compiler.

Comment: GCC or whatever compiler you use makes an educated guess what language you're using in your file. If it has the suffix .c, it assumes C instead of Objective-C. You could however override with compiler flags. In your case however, I don't see any reason not to use the suffix .m.

Comment: To avoid this in the future, when you create the new project, select "Foundation" as the type instead of "C". That will give you a main file that's correctly named, and a main() function that already has an autorelease pool.

Comment: @Shem Pendley, Thanks! Good advice! I will remember that in the future and then select Foundation instead of C.